# Redux: is it an anti-pattern to put much logic and share date between slice reducers in thunks?

Tags: redux

In the Redux Style Guide, it is *strongly recommended* to [Put as Much Logic as Possible in Reducers](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers):

> Wherever possible, **try to put as much of the logic for calculating a
>   new state into the appropriate reducer, rather than in the code that
>   prepares and dispatches the action** (like a click handler).

What I'm not sure of is, if thunks are also considered to be "the code" of some sort. Besides, we've also been (mis?)using thunks to grab data from other slices of state.

Hypothetically simplified code snippet of such thunk:

```js
const addX = x => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { data, view } = getState();
    const { y } = view; // <-- here accessing data from `view` state.

    const yy = doSomeLogicWith(y);
    const z = doSomeMoreLogicWith(yy);

    dispatch({ type: 'data/xAdded', payload: { x, z } });
};
```

Is this actually considered to be an anti-pattern in Redux? If so, what are the cons of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a thunk would qualify as "the code that dispatches the action" for this case.  So, what the rule is recommending here is that if possible, the action would just contain `y`, and the function calls to `doSomeLogicWith(y)` and `doSomeMoreLogicWith(yy)` would ideally exist within the reducer instead.

Having said that, [it's totally fine for a thunk to extract pieces of data from the state and include that in the action](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers), and it's not *wrong* for a thunk to do some pre-processing of data before dispatching the action.

The style guide rule is just saying that, given a choice between running a particular piece of logic in a reducer or outside a reducer, prefer to do it in the reducer if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you @markerikson for your enlightening answer - as always. :) I've got the point now. Just for the sake of completeness: since thunks are _just_ async action creators, it means (sync) action creators would also qualify as "the code that prepares the action" in that paragraph (although it doesn't dispatch it), right?

Comment: Yes, although action creators rarely have any meaningful logic inside - they're usually just `return {type: "todos/addTodo", payload: "Buy milk"}`.